# How to integrate SendGrid into a firebase/node/react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, sendgrid

I am trying to implement sendgrid to my react/firebase project to use as a way for users to send issues to me through the ui. When I try to implement SendGrid into my project there is always some kind of error. My relevant code for the backend is:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = require("express")();
const cors = require("cors");

const auth = require("./util/auth");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// send email
app.post("/send-email", auth, (req, res) => {
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.REACT_APP_SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  const msg = {
    to: "kaseyk@ufl.edu",
    from: "kaseyk@ufl.edu",
    subject: "Sending with SendGrid is Fun",
    text: req.body.text,
  };

  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Email sent");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

My function in the frontend that makes the call is :

```
  const onSubmit = async () => {
    if (text && text.trim() !== "") {
      const authToken = localStorage.getItem("AuthToken");
      axios.defaults.headers.common = { Authorization: `${authToken}` };
      await axios.post("/send-email", text).catch((err) => console.error(err));

      props.onCancel(false);
    }
  };
```

The error is when I try to deploy the function to firebase functions.

> Function failed on loading user code.
> Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs.
> Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging

The logs aren't helpful at all so I don't know what the problem is here. I feel like I'm taking a real big swing and miss with how I am goin about this in the first place

[image]

Comment: Did you do what the error messages says and check the logs using the provided link?  Without that information, you're not likely to get much help from Stack Overflow.

Comment: He or she did, just post the error logs, maybe we don't think they are useless

Comment: added the error logs. Lmk if you see something i dont

Comment: that looks like the service logs, can you go the cloud function and get the logs from the function execution itself?

Comment: Oh I figured that part out. I installed the sendgrid dependency while i was in the parent directory smh. It deployed but now I am getting a 404 error

Comment: which is now a CORS error lol